# Resize buttons on different screen size Android

Tags: android, xml

I need to resize 3 buttons in order to fit every screen size so I tried to use a vertical Linear Layout but the result is the following:

[image]

This is the result I get on the ldpi/mdpi devices, but when I switch to higher resolutions like hdpi I get this:

[image]

the third button gets zoomed.

How can I resize the 3 buttons in order to fit the screen?

Comment: are you using image buttons

Comment: i'm using a button with a background image

Comment: 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi:xxxhdpi , Try to put proper image source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3" >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="b1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="b2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="b3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

place the buttons in a `linearlayout (horizontal)`

add `android:weightSum="3"` to the linear layout

add `android:layout_weight="1"` for each of the `buttons` and make their `layout_width="0dp"`

This will resize the `buttons`(width) responsively on the size of the device.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#5E616B"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_pingsheet"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
            android:src="@drawable/pingicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_myprofile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_mycircle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
            android:src="@drawable/mycircle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sendping"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
            android:src="@drawable/sendping" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The basic concept here is to take a linear layout with **weightsum** 1.Then divide that weight into each of the buttons(**I have taken 5 buttons so divided it as .2 for each**). You can divide the weight with  `android:layout_weight=".2"` attribute.Also dont forget **to set the orientation of the linear layout to horizontal**.